# Optimize pandas dataframe calculation without looping through rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using panda to calculate capital after each trade as follow but wonder if there is any other way to calculate this without looping through every row?
Thanks in advance!!!

**Logic:**

```
trade = 1: buy
trade = -1: sell

diff: <Open> price of sell order - <Open> price of buy order, only calculate after each sell
position: capital/<Open> price, resets after each sell
gain = diff * position, only calculate after each sell
gain_c = gain_c + gain
capital = capital + gain
```

**The code I'm using:**

```
for i in range(1, len(df_trades)):
    if df_trades.loc[i, 'TRADE'] != -1: # BUY order: set POSITION for buy order
        df_trades.loc[i, 'POSITION'] = df_trades.loc[i,'CAPITAL']//df_trades.loc[i,'<Open>']
        df_trades.loc[i,'GAIN'] = 0
        df_trades.loc[i,'GAIN_C'] = df_trades.loc[i -1,'GAIN_C']
    if df_trades.loc[i, 'TRADE'] == -1: # SELL order: recalculate Capital, gain, gain_c
        df_trades.loc[i, 'POSITION'] = 0
        df_trades.loc[i,'DIFF'] = df_trades.loc[i,'<Open>'] - df_trades.loc[i-1,'<Open>']            
        df_trades.loc[i,'GAIN'] = df_trades.loc[i,'DIFF'] * df_trades.loc[i-1,'POSITION']
        df_trades.loc[i,'GAIN_C'] = df_trades.loc[i-1,'GAIN_C'] + df_trades.loc[i,'GAIN']
        df_trades.loc[i,'CAPITAL'] = df_trades.loc[i-1,'CAPITAL'] + df_trades.loc[i,'GAIN']
```

**Expected output:**

```
<Open> TRADE    CAPITAL  POSITION      GAIN    GAIN_C  DIFF
  7.17   1.0  100000.00   13947.0      0.00      0.00   NaN
  7.20  -1.0  100418.41       0.0    418.41    418.41  0.03
  7.19   1.0  100418.41   13966.0      0.00    418.41   NaN
  8.96  -1.0  125138.23       0.0  24719.82  25138.23  1.77
  8.99   1.0  125138.23   13919.0      0.00  25138.23   NaN
```

Comment: You forgot to include the sample input

Comment: hi, the input is in the expected output itself, it's all calculated with Open price and Capital

Comment: @bongkem but the expected output doesn't have a `<Close>` column, which is used in the loop

Comment: oh it's a typo, it's all open price, thanks for spotting that, i'll edit that right away

Comment: Your problem is iterative by nature so you are stuck with some form of looping or apply as suggested below. This is because the Capital value is dependent on the previous row, so I don't believe that you can do a single calculation on the entire DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function with a row input [and output] and [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) it (instead of using the `for` loop) across columns like <kbd>`df_trades = df_trades.apply(calculate_capital, axis=1, from_df=df_trades)`</kbd> where `calculate_capital` is defined as

```py
def calculate_capital(row, from_df):
    if row.name==0: return row
    prev_row = from_df.loc[row.name-1]
    if row['TRADE'] != -1: # BUY order: set POSITION for buy order
        row['POSITION'] = row['CAPITAL']//row['<Open>']
        row['GAIN'] = 0
        row['GAIN_C'] = prev_row['GAIN_C']
    if row['TRADE'] == -1: # SELL order: recalculate Capital, gain, gain_c
        row['POSITION'] = 0
        row['DIFF'] = row['<Close>'] - prev_row['<Open>']            
        row['GAIN'] = row['DIFF'] * prev_row['POSITION']
        row['GAIN_C'] = prev_row['GAIN_C'] + row['GAIN']
        row['CAPITAL'] = prev_row['CAPITAL'] + row['GAIN']
    return row
```

---

**Example**: If I recreate your sample data as `df_trades` with

```py
df_trades = pd.DataFrame([l.split() for l in '''
  7.17   1.0  100000.00   13947.0      0.00      0.00   NaN
  7.20  -1.0  100418.41       0.0    418.41    418.41  0.03
  7.19   1.0  100418.41   13966.0      0.00    418.41   NaN
  8.96  -1.0  125138.23       0.0  24719.82  25138.23  1.77
  8.99   1.0  125138.23   13919.0      0.00  25138.23   NaN
'''.splitlines() if l.strip()], columns='''
  <Open> TRADE    CAPITAL  POSITION      GAIN    GAIN_C  DIFF
'''.split())
df_trades = df_trades.assign(**{'<Close>': 8})[[
    '<Open>','<Close>', 'TRADE','CAPITAL','POSITION', 'GAIN','GAIN_C','DIFF'
]].applymap(float)
```

<sup>**(I added and filled `<Close>` with `8`s since your loop snippet indicated there should be such a column.)**</sup>

The changes in the results below are highlighted in green.

> [image: opdfs]

---

---

In retrospect, I think it might be faster to apply this function:

```py
def calculate_new_row(row):
    if row.name==0: return row
    if row['TRADE'] != -1: # BUY order: set POSITION for buy order
        row['POSITION'] = row['CAPITAL']//row['<Open>']
        row['GAIN'] = 0
        row['GAIN_C'] = row['GAIN_C_prev']
    if row['TRADE'] == -1: # SELL order: recalculate Capital, gain, gain_c
        row['POSITION'] = 0
        row['DIFF'] = row['<Close>'] - row['<Open>_prev']            
        row['GAIN'] = row['DIFF'] * row['POSITION_prev']
        row['GAIN_C'] = row['GAIN_C_prev'] + row['GAIN']
        row['CAPITAL'] = row['CAPITAL_prev'] + row['GAIN']
    return row
```

but after joining (with [`.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)) `df_trades` to a shifted version (via [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html))<sup>([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzdxj.png))</sup>

```py
df_trades = df_trades.join(
    df_trades.shift(), rsuffix='_prev').apply(
        calculate_new_row, axis=1)[df_trades.columns]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i have an impression that the apply method don't go row by row to calculate each Capital  but rather try to do the calculation all at once, right? I try to write the code as you suggest and it generated a bunch of Nan (and do no calculation) for Capital, Gain, Gain_c after row 1.

Comment: @bongkem I wouldn't be able to figure out why that's happening without being able to reproduce your `df_trades` more exactly (like if you add a snippet with the output from `df_trades.to_dict('tight')` to your post), but I've added in a screenshot of what I got with a df generated from parsing your sample snippet, as well as another method which I think would be faster

Comment: that's amazing, i'll try the shifted join approach to optimize the run time, thanks a lot !!!